# Sonarqube taking massive amounts of memory

Tags: continuous-integration, cicd, sonarqube

I am running Sonarqube on a monolithic application on our CI server and the scanner (not the Sonarqube server) is taking over 60GB of memory.

Is this normal?

What can I do so the scanner will not use so much memory during the Sonarqube scan?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the [following article](https://medium.com/swlh/sonarqube-sonarscanner-setup-1a633b654828) on the SonarQube - SonarScanner setup best practices. It will be good if the following [hardware recommendations](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/requirements/hardware-recommendations/)  are considered for the SonarQube installations. Following are some of the important considerations.

- SonarQube server should be on a real DB not on H2.
- The analysis should occur very close to the SonarQube DB.

Comment: I made sure to clarify. It is the scanner that is taking all the memory.

Comment: We made absolutely sure that it is using a real database instead of H2. It is using ?MS SQL  Server. We also checked to see if the database is located in the same datacenter as the jenkins node that runs the scan. They are both in the same datacenter.